# O que é uma arquitetura de microsserviços?

Tags: servidor, arquitetura-de-software

Li que "arquitetura baseada em microsserviços" basicamente torna os requisitos do sistema em serviços específicos e independentes.

[Neste artigo](http://www.infoq.com/br/articles/microservices-intro%20Artigo%20InfoQ), logo após as definições diz que **é possível separar os serviços em instâncias (máquinas) específicas de acordo com a exigência de hardware daquele serviço**.

Minha dúvida é: Para cada serviço é gerado um `WAR`?

Trabalho com uma aplicação separadas em módulos e em 3 camadas: API's, Services e DAO: Isso é ou não considerado uma arquitetura de micro serviços (não isoladas em diferentes instâncias)?

Comment: Achei esse post bem interessante e você vai querer ler para entender um pouco mais: http://www.itexto.net/devkico/?p=1768

Comment: @rray obrigado. eu já tinha visto essa pergunta mas ela não engloba o escopo de SOA, que é o que me gera maior confusão ao comparar com a arquitetura de microsserviços

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Primeiro respostas às estas perguntas que podem ser respondidas de forma mais "simples":

> Para cada serviço é gerado um `WAR`?

Depende, obviamente, das tecnologias/plataforma utilizadas. Em um ambiente real você perceberá que alguns micro serviços podem ser empacotados em `WAR` para serem implantados em containers web Java, mas outros não serão, podem ser um simples JavaScript implantados em um HTTP server.

> Trabalho com uma aplicação separadas em módulos e em 3 camadas: API's, Services e DAO: Isso é ou não considerado uma arquitetura de micro serviços (não isoladas em diferentes instâncias)?

Provavelmente não é uma arquitetura de micro serviços. É provável que esteja mais para uma arquitetura monolítica e iremos ver logo logo o que é isto.

De forma resumida (mas nem tanto :P) podemos dizer que:

- micro serviço é a consequência de quando aplicamos o príncipio da responsabilidade única no nível arquitetural, seja de software, sistemas, etc.
- considerando o dito acima, uma arquitetura orientada a micro serviços pode ser definida como um conjunto de pequenos serviços, cada qual rodando de forma independente e comunicando entre si através de um mecanismo leve, podendo cada micro serviços prover ou não uma forma de interface de usuário. Se olharmos as "entranhas" de cada micro serviço veremos que ele é independente, então fazendo uma comparação com a sua arquitetura, cada micro serviço publicará sua própria API (que inclusive pode ser a forma de integração entre micro serviços), seu próprio(s) DAO(s), etc. A granularidade vai depender da sua necessidade, levando em conta sempre independência, facilidade de escalar, de implantar, etc.
- uma arquitetura monolítica é aquela em que uma aplicação é construída em uma única unidade, considerando a plataforma Java Web, todos os serviços em um mesmo `WAR` seria uma comparação aceitável de como é empacotada uma aplicação concebida de forma monolítica.

Utilizando o enxerto do artigo que você citou:

> ...é possível separar os serviços em instâncias (máquinas) específicas de acordo com a exigência de hardware daquele serviço.

Sim, isto é sim possível com esta arquitetura, mas também o é com outras arquiteturas menos granulares.

O que ganhamos com micro serviços é a alta granularidade que a arquitetura permite, ou seja, podemos ter vários micro serviços em um mesmo servidor e escalarmos em outro servidor apenas outros micro serviços.

Além disto, temos os diversões padrões que são diretamente relacionados à micro serviços, como serviços únicos por máquina virtual ou por *container*, registro e descoberta de serviços, etc.

Nos links abaixo você poderá encontrar detalhadamente o que é uma arquitetura de micro serviços. Como perceberá é bastante grande, então não compensa incluir aqui, o detalhamento seria muito extenso:

- [eMag InfoQ sobre Microservices](http://www.infoq.com/minibooks/emag-microservices)
- [Microservices](http://martinfowler.com/articles/microservices.html) - ponto de partida dos estudos, além das referências neste serem excelentes
- [MonolithFirst](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/MonolithFirst.html)
- [Microservice Architecture](http://microservices.io/): site que compila artigos, apresentações, etc. sobre micro serviços
- Construindo produtos na SoundCloud: [Parte 1](https://developers.soundcloud.com/blog/building-products-at-soundcloud-part-1-dealing-with-the-monolith), [Parte 2](https://developers.soundcloud.com/blog/building-products-at-soundcloud-part-2-breaking-the-monolith) e [Parte 3](https://developers.soundcloud.com/blog/building-products-at-soundcloud-part-3-microservices-in-scala-and-finagle)
- [Testando micro serviços](http://martinfowler.com/articles/microservice-testing/#)
- Sobre Microservices: [Parte 1](http://nginx.com/blog/introduction-to-microservices/), [Parte 2](http://nginx.com/blog/building-microservices-using-an-api-gateway/) e terá até a parte 7, vou atualizando

Além do blog do [Martin Fowler](http://martinfowler.com/tags/microservices.html), veja também os do [Spring](http://spring.io/blog), [nginx](http://nginx.com/blog) e blogs técnicos de empresas que possuem arquiteturas bem granulares e APIs ricas, como [Netflix](http://techblog.netflix.com/), a já citada [SoundCloud](https://developers.soundcloud.com/blog), entre outros, eles sempre publicam alguma coisa sobre como estão utilizando micro serviços para melhorarem a forma de implantação de seus serviços, resposta rápida a mudanças de negócio, escalabilidade, etc.

Como pode ver, já existe bastante conteúdo sobre o assunto. Então, bons estudos =)

Comment: Legal sua resposta, os links que postou etc... muitas pessoas saem dividindo suas aplicações em vários módulos achando que estão utilizando microservices mas na verdade nem um simples SSO chegaram a implementar, arquitetura baseada em microserviços é uma arquitetura muito linda, porém não é uma bala de prata, em certos contextos mais atrabalha do que ajuda, se não for tudo muito bem pensado tem replicação de código, problemas no deploy com integração continua e além, se não for uma equipe de seniors tem grande chance de fracasso, afinal nem todo mundo é uma Netflix :) Parabéns pela resposta.

Answer (score 5):

### **Microserviços**

Microserviços é o desenvolvimento de aplicações como um conjunto de pequenos serviços, onde cada um executa seu próprio processo e podem ser construídos de forma modular, com base na capacidade de negócio da organização em questão. Isso faz com que a implantação e a escalabilidade possam ser tratadas conforme a demanda. Além disso, a independência entre os serviços permitem que eles sejam escritos em diferentes linguagens de programação e diferentes tecnologias, visando atender a necessidades específicas da melhor maneira. Outro ponto importante é que cada serviço pode ser gerenciado por diferentes times de desenvolvimento, possibilitando a formação de equipes especializadas.

**Vantagens:**

- Fácil entendimento e desenvolvimento do projeto;
- Fácil e rápida implantação (build e deploy);
- Redução do tempo de startup, pois os microserviços são menores que aplicações monolíticas em termos de código;
- Possibilidade de aplicar a melhor ferramenta para um determinado trabalho.

**Desvantagens:**

- Dificuldade em implantar e operar sistemas distribuídos;
- Como cada microserviços geralmente tem sua própria base de dados, o gerenciamento de transação se torna mais difícil (múltiplas bases de dados);
- Implantar uma alteração em um serviço utilizado por muitos sistemas demanda coordenação e cautela.

**Comparação com padrão monolítico**

Uma aplicação empresarial é geralmente construída em três partes principais:

- Interface
- Banco de dados
- Aplicação `server-side`

Na parte de interface ficam as páginas HTML e JavaScript, no banco de dados são relacionadas as tabelas e a aplicação `server-side` irá manipular as requisições HTTP, executar a lógica de domínio, receber e atualizar os dados da base de dados e por fim, selecionar e popular os blocos HTML para enviar ao navegador. Esta aplicação é monolítica, é feita como uma única unidade, qualquer mudança feita no sistema terá que ser feita uma nova publicação.

Apesar dessas aplicações serem bem-sucedidas, uma pequena alteração feita em uma parte do software, mesmo que pequena, faz com que toda a aplicação tenha que ser republicada. Com o tempo vai ficando cada vez mais complicado de manter uma estrutura modular. Devido a esses problemas, foi criado o padrão de microserviços.

Essa [imagem](https://martinfowler.com/articles/microservices.html) mostra a comparação entre uma aplicação monolítica e microserviços:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Microserviços e SOA**

SOA significa *Service-Oriented Architecture* (Arquitetura Orientada a Serviços) e é um estilo de arquitetura de software que prega que as funcionalidades implementadas pelas aplicações devem ser disponibilizadas na forma de serviços. Essa [imagem](http://blog.iprocess.com.br/2012/10/soa-arquitetura-orientada-a-servicos/), mostra as principais características do SOA:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Microserviços e SOA são muito semelhantes em princípio, mas os produtos que são alvo SOA ou microserviços têm diferenças que os tornam adequados para diferentes casos de uso.

Se você estiver desenvolvendo um aplicativo, então um framework de microserviços vai ser mais ágil e lhe dará maior controle como desenvolvedor. Se o que você está tentando fazer é orquestrar uma série de processos de negócios em toda a sua empresa, então um produto SOA provavelmente fornece um conjunto melhor de ferramentas.

Referências:

- [O que é arquitetura baseada em micro serviços?](http://www.itexto.net/devkico/?p=1755)
- Recomendo a leitura: [Microsserviços, por Martin Fowler e James Lewis](http://www.pedromendes.com.br/2016/01/02/microservicos/)
- [Microsserviços em poucas palavras](https://www.thoughtworks.com/pt/insights/blog/microservices-nutshell)
- [Arquitetura de microserviços ou monolítica?](http://blog.caelum.com.br/arquitetura-de-microservicos-ou-monolitica/)
- [Microsserviços: O que são e para que servem?](http://www.obomprogramador.com/2015/03/micro-servicos-o-que-sao-e-para-que.html)

Answer (score -2):

Olá,

Pensando em processamento distribuído o ideal é termos varias funcionalidades do sistema desacopladas em modo de serviço.

Por exemplo, temos uma aplicação que apenas "Exibe", "Atualiza", "Insere" e "Deleta" um cliente. Ao invés de termos tudo isso acoplado em um só lugar, seria mais proveitoso termos vários servidos (WCF, WEB SERVICE, JSF) distribuído. Assim para para ganharmos desempenho como estamos falando de serviços podemos ter a aplicação Web em um servidor e os serviços em outro(os).

http://www.itexto.net/devkico/?p=1755

Comment: Luã, se puder fornecer uma resposta mais completa. Já li esse texto, me parece que como é algo relativamente novo ninguém sabe definir "direito".

Comment: Desculpe, não encontrei muita coisa que realmente irá ajuda-la referente a esse assunto. Irei encaminhar sua questão para alguns amigos arquitetos, vamos ver se eles poderão te ajudar.