# O que são microsserviços?

Tags: arquitetura-de-software, microsserviços

Muito se tem falado desses `microsserviços`, parece que vieram para substituir a arquitetura `SOA`. Empresas como *Netflix*, *eBay*, *PayPal* e *Twitter* migraram suas arquiteturas `monolíticas` para arquiteturas de `microsserviços`. Mas, afinal, quais suas vantagens/desvantagens em relação às arquiteturas `monolíticas` e, principalmente, `SOA`?

Comment: [O que é uma arquitetura de microserviços?](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/68899/91)