# Que problema os microserviços resolvem?

Tags: arquitetura-de-software, microsserviços

Ok, já li [O que é uma arquitetura de microserviços?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/68899/101) e artigos sobre o assunto, sei o que é e como funciona. Mas ainda não sei que problema ele tenta resolver.

Quais as vantagens de usá-lo do ponto de vista do desenvolvimento e manutenção de software e do funcionamento da solução?

E as desvantagens? Me parece que ele gera um *overhead*. Dá a impressão que a solução se torna mais complexa.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Já tive uma boa experiência com microserviços, vamos lá:

### *Vantagens:*

**Divisão dos times:** Quando seu sistema cresce e o time de desenvolvimento também acaba vindo a necessidade de quebrar uma equipe grande em equipes menores para facilitar a comunicação e divisão de tarefas. Com o paradigma de microserviços, equipes podem atacar serviços diferentes sem o risco de uma alteração afetar o desenvolvimento da outra equipe (colisões em merges, etc).

**Escalabilidade Seletiva:** Quando você precisa de mais performance no modelo monolítico normalmente você duplica o servidor todo ou aumenta sua capacidade. Com microserviços (ou em qualquer paradigma de sistemas distribuídos), você pode escalar somente a parte do sistema que realmente precisa de mais performance, sem tocar no resto.

**Velocidade de desenvolvimento**: Esta parte só se aplica *depois* que seu sistema todo já está bem maduro e estou falando da parte do código somente. Soluções menores compilam mais rápido e são mais fáceis de trabalhar.

**Liberdade de escolha de tecnologias:** Cada microserviço pode ser escrito na linguagem e utilizar o banco de dados mais interessante para resolução daquele problema em específico. Novas tecnologias/frameworks podem ser testados de forma rápida e contida.

**Atualização rápida de frameworks:** Como cada microserviço é independente, fica mais fácil subir a versão de certo framework sem medo de side-effects em outras partes do sistema. O trabalho também é menor, já que a solução é bem pequena e pode simplesmente ser reescrita se for este o caso.

### *Desvantagens*

**Setup:** O setup de sua aplicação pode ficar muiiito mais longo dependendo do seu contexto. Há de se pensar em API Gateways, service discovery e todo o orquestramento dos microserviços, coisas que normalmente não são necessárias em aplicações monolíticas.

**CORS:** Se você fizer chamadas AJAX para vários serviços, pode ter o problema de CORS. Isto pode ser resolvido com uma API Gateway/Proxy reverso (mais trabalho, mais itens para gerenciar).

**Autenticação:** Mesma coisa que o CORS, pode ser resolvido de várias formas (API Gateways + tokens por exemplo), mas gera muito mais trabalho no início.

**Logs:** logs são descentralizados e devem ser centralizados em algum lugar para diagnóstico completo.

**Deploy:** Esta é a pior parte. Se você já tem problemas com deploy com sua aplicação monolítica, nem pense em microserviços. Todos os problemas vão ser multiplicados pelo número de serviços, já que ao invés de 1 único e simples deploy, você tem que fazer vários.

**Teste:** Testar a aplicação como um todo dá muito mais trabalho no sandbox de cada desenvolvedor. Debug de ponta a ponta fica mais complexo já que você vai estar trabalhando com cada serviço. Tecnologias de containers podem ajudar.

**API Gateway Bottleneck:** Se você tem uma equipe cuidando da API Gateway, ela pode virar seu bottleneck de desenvolvimento se no seu caso cada nova funcionalidade tem que passar por ali.

**Backup:** Como cada microserviço acaba tendo sua base de dados separada, você vai ter muito mais backups para fazer e gerenciar.

**Transações:** Com várias bases de dados você vai ter o problema de transações distribuídas e talvez alguma replicação de dados.

### *Conclusão*

O paradigma de Microserviços está na moda e muita gente está usando sem parar muito para pensar nos prós e contras. Não há nada de errado com aplicações monolíticas, tudo depende do seu contexto.

Como em qualquer decisão de uso de alguma tecnologia, a pergunta que você tem que fazer é:

**Qual problema eu quero resolver com microserviços? E quais problemas eu vou introduzir com eles? Vale a pena?**

E uma última dica:

*Se sua empresa não tem uma cultura forte de **devops**, esqueça Microserviços. Fomente e fortaleça essa cultura e somente quando estiverem muito bons nisso comecem a pensar nesse paradigma. Deploy vai ser peça primordial no sucesso ou no fracasso de um sistema deste tipo.*

Comment: Bom esclarecimento, mas algumas das desvantagens não são inerentes à arquitetura de microserviços, mas a políticas e tecnologias não (ou mal) implementadas e que trazem problemas tanto num cenário quanto no outro, como o deploy problemático, por exemplo.

Comment: Olá @dellasavia, sim, mas independente de sua maturidade com deploy, é sempre mais caro e complicado fazer deploy de várias aplicações do que de uma só.

Comment: Em tempo, se quiser ver um exemplo de vida real, dê uma lida sobre o Predix (http://www.predix.io) que a GE (General Electric) lançou. É uma plataforma para IIoT (Internet Industrial das Coisas) baseada em microserviços.

Answer (score 13):

## Dividir para Conquistar

É meio que um clichê, mas é basicamente isso. Vou tentar colocar o que eu entendo que a arquitetura tenta resolver, mas é claro que o assunto é bem extenso. 
De forma resumida eu colocaria os seguintes pontos abaixo como principais.

- Complexidade de funcionalidades e de integração.
- Grande volume de transações que demandam tempo de resposta baixo.
- Diversidade de tecnologias e disciplinas.
- Custos de serviços em nuvem.

Os sistemas tem a tendência de ficarem mais complexos conforme eles vão agregando novas tecnologias de acesso e novas funcionalidades que os usuários demandam. Com a quebra de um sistema em partes menores focadas em uma função fica mais simples o entendimento do problema e sua solução. Não é necessário, por exemplo, que todo o time conheça todo o funcionamento do sistema para construir e evoluir. A arquitetura prevê que cada serviço terá uma separação clara do seu domínio fornecendo interfaces de entrada e saída que usam apenas o domínio para o qual a função foi projetada.

A separação também facilita o processo de testes, planejamento e controle das funções, uma vez que normalmente as empresas colocam times pequenos e focados em cada função para que as mudanças e a evolução aconteça de forma ágil.

A ideia de ter as partes separadas também permite que tecnologias diferentes possam ser utilizadas para resolver problemas diferentes. Uma vez que uma interface de entrada e saída e protocolos de comunicação estejam definidos, as partes não precisa ser todas desenvolvidas com uma mesma tecnologia. Com essa separação também é possível instanciar várias vezes os mesmos serviços e distribuir o processamento.

Outra necessidade de dividir em partes também tem a ver com o custo dos serviços em nuvem. As empresas que oferecem esses serviços cobram por uso e poder de processamento dos recursos. Assim, se você tem um sistema monolítico vai precisar de uma infraestrutura bem grande para colocar no ar e escalar. Com a separação, você pode ter, por exemplo, ter 5 instâncias leves, para atender 100 usuários que usam o módulo de faturamento, uma instância leve rodando para atender aos 10 usuários do módulo de compras e uma instância mais pesada rodando relatórios de consolidação.

A ideia não é nova. O SOA (arquitetura orientada a serviços) também prega uma separação dos sistemas em partes menores e mais fáceis de gerenciar. Acredito que essas tentativas de sair dos sistemas monolíticos é algo que sempre está sendo tentado. Eu entendo que a arquitetura de micro-serviços foca mais em como fazer do que no conceitual, por isso talvez está ganhando mais força.

É claro que na teoria parece tudo muito bom, mas no lado das desvantagens o problema é fazer essas partes funcionarem, tanto no lado do sistema como lado das equipes de desenvolvimento. A separação traz uma maior complexidade para fazer o sistema todo funcionar e nesse ponto é que entra a parte do *DevOps* que é a outra parte que pode se chamar de "tendência", que faz todo sentido quando você adota essa arquitetura distribuída. Sem uma boa comunicação entre a operação de infraestrutura com os times de desenvolvimento não tem com isso funcionar de forma ágil.

A outra desvantagem de separar tem a ver com a integração dos dados. Como tudo fica separado existe um esforço adicional, porque tudo acaba sendo replicado para que funcione de forma separada e a sincronização para juntar os dados para um relatório consolidado ou mesmo para não duplicar informações de cadastros comuns, como de clientes, produtos, etc. requer que os desenvolvedores passem a utilizar outras técnicas e tecnologias com por exemplo banco de dados NoSQL que se adapta bem nesse cenário distribuído e eventualmente consistente. Normalmente os desenvolvedores estão acostumados com os bancos SQL que controlam toda a parte de consistência dos dados e essa mudança não é muito fácil de fazer para quem está muito tempo trabalhando com SQL.

Tem muito mais a ser explorado e os melhores artigos (curtos) que já li sobre o assunto e deixo a indicação são os do [Martin Fowler](https://martinfowler.com/articles/microservices.html),  do [Chris Richardson](https://www.infoq.com/articles/microservices-intro) e do [Robert Sheldon](https://www.simple-talk.com/cloud/cloud-development/microservices-in-promise-and-practice/)