# Arquitetura on Promisse e Cloud

Tags: arquitetura-de-software

O cenário seria uma grande aplicação ERP, ela podera ser hospedada em on promisse ou na nuvem de acordo com a necessidade do cliente.

Qual seria a melhor forma de atender esse tipo de arquitetura ?

Arquitetura de banco de dados Centralizada ou distribuida ?

Aplicação Monolitica ou Microserviço ?

Usar docker para o banco e a aplicação ou não, ou utilizar docker somente para as aplicações ?

Comment: Sem mais informações não dá para responder, então não está clara, ou está muito ampla ou até beira a pedido de pura opinião. Apesar do assunto ser relevante e útil. Eu gosto do KISS do YAGNI https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/23052/101. Então de cara vou de centralizado, se for o meso que eu entendo do termo e monolítica, até que se mostre necessário fazer de outra forma. Ainda não tenho opinião formada sobre Docker, não tenho tanta certeza quanto alguns que é sempre bom.

Comment: Concordo com @bigown, será muito de opinião. Fuja do monolitico, e esqueça centralização de banco de dados. Docker não faz parte da sua solução final, isso é estratégia de Hospedam. Aqui onde trabalho usamos Docker em ambiente de desenvolvimento e testes automatizado, e PaaS em ambiente de, homologação e produção. Microservices não é o oposto de monolitico.

Comment: @ThiagoLunardi pra mim é novidade microsserviços não ser o oposto de monolítico, a não ser que esteja falando de algo híbrido queria saber mais, se puder ser fundamentado. Cabe uma resposta em https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/194663/101 ou acha que devo fazer uma pergunta mais específica?

Comment: Isso é um engano comum. O fato de se pegar um sistema monolitico e quebrar em partes, essas partes não necessariamente serão microservices, podem ser apenas serviços, com contextos delimitados, tudo certinho, mas sem nada de micro.

Comment: Se eu bolar uma forma de mudar sua pergunta para ficar em condições de responder posso editar para salvá-la? Claro que você poderá reverter se achar que mudei demais o que deseja saber, ainda que isto provavelmente provocará o fechamento dela.

Comment: @ThiagoLunardi entendi, isso eu sei, é que aí não deixa de ser o oposto, é que tem meio termo também.

Comment: Ramon Durães explica com um exemplo bem pertinente do que pode ser considerado um microservices nesse vídeo https://youtu.be/YOLFN_Du9E8

Comment: @ThiagoLunardi já tinbha visto esse e outros vídeos do Ramon. Não tenha opinião 100% formada, porque é cedo demais para alguém ter. Mas quanto mais eu aprendo sobre microsserviços, mais eu acho que ele feio para resolver um problema que não existia antes das pessoas adotarem soluções que não era necessárias. Eu tenho visto que MS é algo muito de nicho, embora eu ache que esse nicho irá crescer muito (do ponto de vista de engenharia, do ponto de vista de marketing as coisas crescem sem necessidade mesmo, o que não me interessa), ou pro que eu disse antes.

Comment: O que o Ramon diz claramente é algo para resolver com aplicações especializadas monolíticas, que até pode se comportar como um macrosserviço, e não com MS, mas tá na moda, então todo mundo vai nela. É uma pena. Até os defensores reconhecem que é muito mais complicado trabalhar com ela. Tem que ter necessidade pra justificar.

Comment: Sim, isso mesmo. Resumindo, não concordo nenhum pouco com a prática monolitico, e implantar microservices quando aplicável.

Comment: Bem complicado, esse tema. muito obrigado pelas opiniões.