# Quais são as opções arquitetural de banco de dados para microserviços?

Tags: banco-de-dados, arquitetura-de-software, microsserviços

Recentemente conheci o padrão arquitetural chamado de [SAGA ou as Business Transactions](https://blog.couchbase.com/saga-pattern-implement-business-transactions-using-microservices-part/). E pesquisando encontrei esta [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/276755/como-integrar-microsservi%C3%A7os) também falando do padrão SAGA.

Existe outros padrões além do SAGA?

Comment: Relacionada ou duplicata: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/276755/101

Comment: @Maniero está relacionado. Esta foi a pergunta que comentei na minha pergunta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Banco de dados por serviço
- Banco de dados compartilhado
- Saga
- API Composition
- CQRS
- Domain Event
- Event Sourcing

No site abaixo tem uma descrição um pouco mais detalhada de cada um desses padrões na seção "Gerenciamento de dados".

Fonte: 
https://microservices.io/patterns/index.html