# Relacionamento entre microsserviços

Tags: arquitetura-de-software, microsserviços

Mesmo após ler e assistir vários conteúdos sobre microsserviços ainda estou com uma pulga atrás da orelha que não me deixa em paz.

Vamos considerar microsserviços rodando perfeitamente, cada qual com seu DB, e em um determinado momento eu preciso relacionar os dados de cada um, ou estaria equivocado?

Por exemplo, tenho um microsserviço que processa pedidos de compras, um microsserviço que controla o estoque e um microsserviço de clientes.

Basicamente quando eu precisar fazer um relatório para exibir a quantidade de compra por cliente com suas respectivas movimentações de estoque por produto, sei lá, algo do tipo.

Se quiserem imaginar um cenário semelhante, apenas preciso entender como eu resolveria essa situação com microsserviços? Em um cenário monolítico é um tapa e estaria resolvido.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Um dos motivos que ainda não entendeu o conceito é que ainda pensa como macrosserviços. Controle de estoque é um microsserviço?!?!

Não há definição de tamanho para um microsserviço, mas certamente ele tem uma única responsabilidade. Pedido de compras pode parecer que é único, mas não é. Clientes já pode, talvez, ser um microsserviço.

E sim, de fato os dados precisam se relacionar em algum momento. As duas estratégias básicas são:

- cada microsserviço tem todos os dados necessários para executar o que precisa, recebendo notificações de outros microsserviços sempre que algo foi atualizado lá, então você tem tudo "fresco";
- o microsserviço é um coordenador que faz todo relacionamento no momento que precisa.

O primeiro gera uma ineficiência brutal porque quase toda atualização é desperdiçada. Para tudo isso dar certo as coisas precisam ser mais engessadas que um ambiente monolítico, o que é um contrassenso porque dizem que microsserviço facilita a manutenção. Sim, é verdade, facilita, porque praticamente proíbe fazer muita coisa. Os casos mais famosos de microsserviços tem muito pouca manutenção importante no sistema.

Os casos mais famosos são sistemas mantidos por milhares de programares. Muito provavelmente bem mais do que seria necessário em um sistema monolítico.

[image: Um mau programador pode criar facilmente dois novos empregos por ano.]

Por que tem essa imagem? Porque quase sempre apenas programadores ruins adotam soluções complexas quando a simples resolvia. E microsserviço quase sempre é a solução complexa que as pessoas não precisam.

Imagina um microsserviço de relatório de pedidos receberam atualização sempre que algo mudou nos pedidos ou coisas relacionadas aos pedidos que estão no relatório, sendo que tudo isso precisa ser atualizado em todo lugar, quanto desperdício ocorre entre você precisar do relatório uma vez e a outra.

Imagine como é complicado ficar mexendo em certos serviços sabendo que pode ter muitos usos que você não tem controle usando isso que você prometeu fornecer?

A segunda forma não é tão usada assim, e até tem sido evitada, e é criar na sua aplicação o que o banco de dados relacional sempre fez de forma ótima, quando a pessoa sabe usá-lo. Se a pessoa não sabe usar o DB corretamente, como ela vai reproduzir o que o DB faz na sua aplicação?

Você transforma um problema que deveria ser específico, e isso é mais fácil de resolver, em um problema genérico, que é mais difícil.

Existem motivos legítimos para adotar essa arquitetura, e um deles é que você já tinha um problema genérico de qualquer forma. Outro é tudo ser isolado naturalmente.

## Conclusão

É extremamente difícil fazer isso de forma correta? Sim, é. É considerado o problema mais difícil da computação.

Então a resposta é que você não resolveria isso com microsserviço, isso não deveria ser chamado de solução, é um problema extra que você não precisa ter.

Microsserviços podem funcionam melhor quando eles existem de forma natural, ou seja, é tudo isolado mesmo, não tem muitos relacionamentos. Os problemas que você está dando de exemplo não precisam e não funcionam bem como microsserviços. Ainda que tenha gente fazendo isso, é só por moda, é só porque viram outros fazendo e acham sexy fazer também, elas se sentem bem em fazer algo assim. Agora volte seus olhos pra cima, dê *scroll* se for necessário, e olhe a imagem de novo. Em geral programadores ruins [não percebem que eles são assim](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dunning%E2%80%93Kruger_effect).

Existem problemas legítimos para usar esse técnica, mas são extremamente raros e a esmagadora maioria dos programadores nunca chegarão perto de um problema assim.

Este site é um dos 30 mais acessados do mundo e não precisa disso. Wikipedia, Instagram e outros não precisam. Conheço muito o mundo de ERPs e nenhum nunca precisou disso.

A adoção tende ser mais por motivos políticos do que técnicos (a equipe quer por isso no currículo, querem estar na moda, ou há brigas entre as várias partes da equipe).

É isso que quase todos programadores precisam saber sobre o assunto. Se por acaso a pessoa precisar fazer algo com microsserviço de forma adequada, onde realmente faça sentido, ela será muito boa em computação como um todo e trabalhará em uma equipe enorme com qualificação semelhante. Então é bom saber um pouco, mas quase ninguém precisa aprender de fato como fazer.

Se tiver uma equipe enorme, se ela for bem qualificada, de verdade, que seja gente que não segue modas, que só vira adepta de algo com provas que aquilo será melhor, se for tudo certo, é quase garantido que essa equipe não adotará arquitetura de microsserviços (pode adotar algum microsserviço pontual, de autenticação por exemplo).

Eu sei que gera polêmica, mas sim, eu estou dizendo que a maioria das pessoas (não todas) que estão adotando essa arquitetura são incompetentes por definição.

Para mais detalhes: [Como integrar microsserviços?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/276755/101).

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Excelente explicação, realmente no meu cenário, que não é ERP, eu definitivamente não precisaria de microsserviços porque o monolito me atende suficientemente. Mas mesmo assim, em meio às buscas, descobri uma solução agradável ao problema exposto, se chama CQRS. Acho que é interessante quando o uso de microsserviços são indispensáveis. Obrigado.

Comment: CQRS é exatamente o que eu disse, uma complexidade enorme que quase ninguém precisa. As pessoas adoram cair no conto da novidade modinha. Novamente, Há casos de uso, mas quase ninguém precisa disso.

Comment: Maravilha, obrigado pela explicação. :D